# Copying bulk documents (pdf files) from server to client machine with one click?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

1. User selects the number of files (could be in 100s or 100s)
2. User clicks on the Download link.
3. User is presented a popup to provide the path on the client machine where the files are to be copied.
4. After providing the path, user clicks on Save button on the popup.
5. All the files would be copied from the server to the specified path on the client machine.

What could be the best way to achieve this with a J2EE based framework?

Answer (score 1):

[`java.util.zip`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/zip/package-summary.html) has classes that can assist you in creating a ZIP archive of the files.

Answer (score 1):

I've never actually done this, but have thought about it from time to time:

**Use MIME's multipart content type ability.**

A quick google found detailed instructions in [Download multiple files in one http request](http://www.motobit.com/tips/detpg_multiple-files-one-request/), although it is in ASP/VBS.